# Can I put memory from a 2.7GHz Mac Mini into a 2.4 GHz MacBook?

Tags: memory

A colleague has just upgraded the memory in his spanking new 2.7GHz Core i7 Mac Mini from 4Gb to 8Gb. This means he's got 2x2Gb PC3-10600 (1333MHz) modules kicking around.

I have a Mid-2010 model 2.4GHz Core 2 MacBook which has 2x1Gb PC3-8500 (1067MHz) modules.

So, my question: can I replace the memory in my MacBook with his spare modules? Does the speed mismatch matter? Will it just "downgrade" to the speed my MacBook's expecting, work but be worse (slower) than the memory I have now, or just not work at all? (Or, worst case, fry my MacBook?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this attempted a couple times, each times putting faster clocked RAM into a machine designed for something slower - same machine as yours, the white unibody.

It might turn on, but it likely won't boot - just hang at the Apple logo.

Comment: Accepting this answer as I've tried installing the memory tonight and the machine just beeps and flashes the power light. Put the original memory back and the machine boots fine (thankfully!)